# Правильны ли пунктуация и орфография?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1. В связи с производственной необходимостью, сотрудникам Товарищества установить лимит на мобильную связь в марте месяце, текущего года, согласно приложению №1 к настоящему приказу.
2. Главному бухгалтеру (Ив.... С.Н.) произвести начисление стоимости услуги  мобильной связи к заработной плате марта месяца, текущего года, согласно приложению №1 к настоящему приказу.

Comment: После "месяца" в обоих примерах не может быть запятой, а после запятой перед "согласно" должен быть пробел. "Начислить стоимость" **к** зарлате нельзя, можно "причислить", или можно начислить (сотрудникам) _прибавку_ к зарплате, в размере стоимости услуги.

Answer (score 1):

Не углубляясь в суть невозможности начисления стоимости к зарплате, скажу, что канцелярит живёт по своим законам, как начальник канцелярии положит.

Русскому же языку не требуется ни одна запятая - ни в пункте первом, ни во втором; ещё чего терпеть не может русский язык, так это "марта месяца", как будто наличествует другой март, не месяц.

*1. В связи с производственной необходимостью сотрудникам Товарищества установить лимит на мобильную связь в марте текущего года согласно приложению № 1 к настоящему приказу.*

*2. Главному бухгалтеру (Иваницкому С. Н.) произвести начисление стоимости услуги мобильной связи к заработной плате в марте текущего года согласно приложению № 1 к настоящему приказу.*

---

Между знаком номера и цифрой ставится пробел, но не на переносе, как невольно получилось у меня.

Comment: Спасибо! Но,моя начальница уверена,что перед "сотрудникам" ставится запятая. А после "в марте" нужно "месяца"

Comment: Спросите её, знает ли она март - не месяц? А запятую ей хочется не перед "сотрудникам", а закрыть предложный оборот "в связи с производственной необходимостью". Объясните, что такие распространённые предлоги обособляются, только если расположены между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: @катя В справочнике Лопатина упоминается выражение "в марте месяце" (в том разделе говорится, что "март месяц" пишется раздельно, не через дефис).